# R caret calibration function

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, calibration

I'm studying about calibration techniques and I'd like to use the CARET calibration function to examine the quality of my classifiers' probabilities.

I read the relevant documentation, however I don't seem to get the technique used to calibrate the fitted probabilities.

What is the technique used in the CARET calibration function?